# how to identity what as "filled" my filesystem

Tags: disk-usage

for some reason, My / is full at 100%.
I tried at first to delete some unwanted files ( like apt-get clean ), which free some space, but it wen back to 100%.

I tried to search for the latest files created in last 5 min , 10 min ( ie : find / -cmin 5 ) . Nothing significant .
any suggestion or method to investigate and find the issue ?
Thanks !

Comment: btw, tried as well to identify "big files" , nothing bigger than 1024K... ( ie : du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10). I assume something creating many files, little by little ...

Comment: That may depend a great deal on what's installed on your system and what logs may be generated. Can you provide more details about what Ubuntu system you have, what packages are installed and what the system is used for?

Comment: Sure, it is a 18.04. It is used as firewall with IPtables. I checked in /var/log/ ...no new files created... I herited of that system, I did not installed or maintained it so far :(

Comment: You probably want to include info from your comment in your original question, alongside other details. For example, when you used `apt-get clean`, how much space in % was freed? How long did it take to go back to 100%. Any information such as this can help pinpoint the issue. I am not familiar with IPtables but if it's used as firewall it is plausible that logs are being written somewhere, perhaps a customized location.

Comment: start with /var/log/ and check for large files with `ls -ltr`. If there are ... check the last few lines for notices you can try to fix. Then empty that file with `> {logfile}`

Comment: If you can, start `Disk Usage Analyzer`. If you can't, then do `ls -alS /var/log` and see what pops up at the top of the list.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is that I have nothing in log...
root@bastion:/var/log# du -h
14M     ./installer/cdebconf
16M     ./installer
12K     ./fsck
112K    ./apt
4.0K    ./snort
4.0K    ./dist-upgrade
32K     ./proftpd
56K     ./unattended-upgrades
4.0K    ./lxd
32K     ./mysql
4.0K    ./ntpstats
2.6M    ./squid
19M     .

Comment: We have decided to resintall from scratch the machine ... there are too many other unknown on it .... Thanks to all for your suggestions and help

Answer (score 0):

**You should try [filelight](https://github.com/KDE/filelight).**

Filelight allows you to understand exactly where your diskspace is being used by graphically representating your filesystem as a set of concentric segmented-rings.

Filelight is available in `universe` repositories.  You can install it using your GUI package manager, or with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install filelight
```

Comment: Thanks ! I do not have a Graphical env available , so can not use such tool. Anyway, I did a fresh reinstall , and no more space disapearing ;-) Thanks for the suggestion !